# PostgreSQL - 9.x convert MD5 password to SHA256

Tags: postgresql

How do I convert an existing `md5` password to `sha256` in PostgreSQL 9.x database for security reasons?

We have a production app that has thousands of user passwords stored in md5. Now the security team is saying to get rid of md5 and use sha256. I have only option to convert md5 existing password to sha256 (Looking for some kind of function which help me to migrate md5 to sha256).

Comment: https://blog.dbi-services.com/migrating-your-users-from-md5-to-scram-authentication-in-postgresql/ and https://info.crunchydata.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-postgresql-passwords-to-scram

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to set the password again.

Since PostgreSQL doesn't store the original password, but a hash of it, it is impossible to recover the original password to hash it again with some other algorithm.